# Example for Tensorflow prediction with more than one independent variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0, prediction

I am searching for an example to predict data with Tensorflow. I already tried some codes but I am a beginner in Tensorflow and Python.
For example I predict a stock price by training and testing with old stock prices. Now I would like to integrate more than only the old stock prices, like trade volume, to predict future stock prices.
How can I implement this?

Comment: For your problem, you can make use of multivariate linear regression or other Machine Learning techniques(available in sklearn and/or other libraries). Tensorflow is majorly useful if you want to use neural networks. Do you want to use neural networks? If yes, then this might help you. https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so it's hard to give specific advice.  If you're a beginner in python, I would not recommend Tensorflow as the place to start.  I would assume that if you're using historical prices to predict future prices, then you're trying to make predictions as a time series?  I'd recommend you check out the machinelearningmastery series on time series prediction.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/findings-comparing-classical-and-machine-learning-methods-for-time-series-forecasting/

Specifically to your question, here is a tutorial for many different models using multivariate inputs.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-machine-learning-models-for-multivariate-multi-step-air-pollution-time-series-forecasting/

Once you get more comfortable with modeling, then I'd recommend you check out the notebooks from the machine learning competition site kaggle.com.  They did a stock market prediction competition, and there are a lot of examples of different models people built to predict stock market returns within the parameters of the competition.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-news/notebooks